# How to set up alert on a custom metric in Stackdriver Monitoring?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, heapster, google-cloud-monitoring

When I try to create an alerting policy in Stackdriver Monitoring, my custom metrics do not show up in the dropdown list. When I try to add a chart in the Stackdriver Monitoring dashboard, they show up. Is there something more I need to do to make these custom metrics alertable?

These custom metrics were created using heapster on kubernetes.
I'm still on the Stackdriver Premium trial.

Here is a screenshot of the resource type list when creating a chart.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the resource type list when creating an alerting policy condition.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jesse,Can u help me getting custom metrics using stackdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have access to alert on the same custom metrics in the dropdown, and be able to choose "Custom Metrics" as the RESOURCE TYPE. Maybe check your permissions / logged in account, it could be different between the two cases. If it isn't, hit the "Send Feedback" button at the bottom right of the screen and add my name to the text.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Amir. I just hit "Send Feedback" and added your name. When do you think I can expect to hear back?

Comment: Okay, it looks like open-source k8 has configured Heapster to send metrics to the gcm sink, and the released versions of Heapster upto and incl v1.3.0-beta.0, use the deprecated v2 monitoring API. Stackdriver no longer supports alerting on v2 custom metrics - that's why you're not seeing them in the drop down.
To fix this, either install Heapster from the master branch in github or wait for and install the next released version that fixes this.

Comment: For anyone else who might be interested, I think the relevant pull request is this one.
https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/pull/1480

Comment: Looks like, a new GKE sink will also be available in case that fits better. I haven't tried it.
https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/pull/1538